# How to debug SSL traffic android

Tags: java, android, ssl

I want debug all input/output SSL traffic(like a proxy) on android application. I read it can be done with [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html). Not a fiddler or a charles, only android application.
Maybe anybody have a source to create this functional?